# "Next" Button disabled until values are selected and typed in DropDownLists and Textboxes in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, button

I am using MVC-Viewmodel, EF model first on my project.

I have 3 DropDonLista and a few TextBoxes in my View, User can select Values in the DropDownLists and Type inside the TextBoxes. I want that my "Next" button is disabled until values are selected and textboxes are filled then it gets enabled.

How can I easiest way accomplish this?

I've done this kind of things with C# Winforms and its pretty easy but in MVC I have no clue how I can do this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: My blog Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx does does this.

Comment: I would suggest NOT doing this.  It's considered poor usability.  End users may get confused as to why they can't click next.  It's better to allow them to click next, and do validation on the required fields.  Don't make the users use psychic powers to figure out what they need to do to move on.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I am using Jquery validation plugin now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a client side scripting language like JavaScript. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a framework to make JavaScript easier to use) is now integrated in to MVC3+, so implementing it is much easier than it has been in the past.

You can target HTML DOM elements (HTML tags in your page, in layman terms) in jquery using "selectors" - i.e. if you want to access a HTML textbox called "test" in your form, and check the value, you can do the following:

```
var value = $("#test").val();
if(value == '') {
    // do something
}
```

JavaScript syntax is strikingly similar to C#, but it works on the client side (it's processed by the browser), rather than the server.

Comment: Is there any examples or tutorials for this?

Comment: The JQuery website I have linked above contains all the information you need - alternatively, a quick Google will give you a vast array of tutorials, examples and community support. JQuery is probably the most used JavaScript framework available today.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript/jquery to check if values are selected and textboxes are filled then enable the next button.